# How to count only filtered cells within a function that counts cells of a certain color

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is my function for counting colored cells within a sheet. However, I need to add another variable which counts only the cells displayed, after filtering the data.

```
function countColoredCells(countRange,colorRef) {
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var activeformula = activeRange.getFormula();
  var countRangeAddress = activeformula.match(/\((.*)\,/).pop().trim();
  var backGrounds = activeSheet.getRange(countRangeAddress).getBackgrounds();
  var colorRefAddress = activeformula.match(/\,(.*)\)/).pop().trim();
  var BackGround = activeSheet.getRange(colorRefAddress).getBackground();
  var countCells = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < backGrounds.length; i++)
    for (var k = 0; k < backGrounds[i].length; k++)
      if ( backGrounds[i][k] == BackGround )
        countCells = countCells + 1;
  return countCells;
};
```

If I filter the raw data, it still displays the count of ALL data. I then tried to nest the function within the following function:

```
function applyOverdueFilter() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  var newData= ss.filter(function countColoredCells(countRange,colorRef) {
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var activeformula = activeRange.getFormula();
  var countRangeAddress = activeformula.match(/\((.*)\,/).pop().trim();
  var backGrounds = activeSheet.getRange(countRangeAddress).getBackgrounds();
  var colorRefAddress = activeformula.match(/\,(.*)\)/).pop().trim();
  var BackGround = activeSheet.getRange(colorRefAddress).getBackground();
  var countCells = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < backGrounds.length; i++)
    for (var k = 0; k < backGrounds[i].length; k++)
      if ( backGrounds[i][k] == BackGround )
        countCells = countCells + 1;
  return countCells;
}
```

Any help is appreciated,

Comment: As far as I know there is the only way to exclude filtered rows. And it's a not exactly nice and efficient way. You have to loop through the rows and check them with `sheet.isRowHiddenByFilter(row)` or `sheet.isRowHiddenByUser(row)` methods: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#isrowhiddenbyfilterrowposition

Comment: As a work around if you know the criteria of the filter you can imitate the filter within the script if you will check if values in cells met the same (as the applied filter has) conditions and exclude or include the rows in your counter.